# SQL insert using RAND() for inserting random value - INSERT into TINYINT?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL Insert and I am using `RAND` to generate a random `INT` value the issue is it wont insert into the DB as the column accepts `TINYINT`, How can I convert the output to `TINYINT`. Code example Below:

```
INSERT INTO table (`col`, `col` VALUES (NULL, CAST(FLOOR(5+RAND()*(1-5)) AS CHAR);
```

So I want to randomly insert a number between 1 and 5 which works, however, because the column is set to `TINYINT` and not `INT` i get 1592 unsafe statement. And the DB sets the col to its default value 1.

How can I use `RAND` to enter a random value through using an `INSERT INTO` a `TINYINT` col?

Comment: If the column is `TINYINT`, then why are you casting it to `CHAR` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table (`col1`, `col2`)
VALUES
    (NULL, FLOOR(1 + RAND( )*5));
```

Comment: Thanks, This has worked, however, I still get unsafe statement? not really sure what that error means?

Comment: This is a [known issue](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=49222), which may or may not affect you.

Comment: Dont think it really matters

Comment: @Speedychuck it means don't use `binlog_format=STATEMENT`.  Set it in config to `MIXED` or `ROW`.  Nobody should be using `STATEMENT` -- it's only the default for legacy reasons.

Answer (score 0):

[Function `FLOOR()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor) already returns a number:

> For exact-value numeric arguments, the return value has an exact-value numeric type. For string or floating-point arguments, the return value has a floating-point type.

... so you don't need to cast it to any other type. However, if you do, just don't choose `CHAR` as target type.